# Prime divisors of $a^{p - 1} + \ldots + a + 1$ for $p$ odd prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $p$ prime and odd, $a \in \Bbb Z$, $n=a^{p-1}+...+a+1$. How to prove:

Prime divisors of 
$n =\begin{cases}
       p,     & \text{or} \\
       2px+1, & \text{$x\in \Bbb N$}
    \end{cases}$

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking here. Any other conditions on $a$?

Comment: Note that your sum is just $\frac{a^p - 1}{a - 1}$. By Fermat's theorem, $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$, so it isn't divisible by $p$.

Comment: @vonbrand What if $a$ is $1$ mod $p$?

Comment: @vonbrand I don't see why any further conditions on $a$ are necessary.  This would probably have been well-known to Euler.

Comment: @TaraB on other question $a^i :a=1,...,p-1$ but this question :$a^i :i=0,...,p-1$

Comment: @vonbrand on other question $a^i :a=1,...,p-1$ but this question :$a^i :i=0,...,p-1$

Comment: To clarify, I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question (but it's highly likely that it is *some* duplicate).  This is a geometric series and the other question is about moments.

Comment: @agustin:  Sorry, I don't actually think it's a duplicate either.  I was too hasty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$ If odd prime $q\mid a, n\equiv1\pmod q\implies q\not\mid n$

$(2)$ Else if $q\mid(a-1)\iff a\equiv1\pmod q\implies a^r\equiv1\pmod q$ for integer $r\ge0$

So, $n\equiv\sum_{0\le r\le p-1}1\pmod q\equiv p\pmod q$

So, $q$ will divide $n$ iff $q\mid p\implies q=p$ as $p,q$ are primes.

$(3)$ Else $q\not\mid a\implies (a,q)=1$ and 
$q\not\mid (a-1)\implies (a-1,q)=1$
$\implies (a(a-1),q)=1$

Now, $n=\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}\implies q\mid \frac{a^p-1}{a-1}\implies q(a-1)\mid (a^p-1) \implies q\mid (a^p-1)$ as $(a-1,q)=1$

Using Fremat's Little Theorem, $a^{q-1}\equiv1\pmod q\implies ord_qa\mid (p,q-1)$

But $(p,q-1)=1$ or $p$ as $p$ is prime

If $(p,q-1)=1, ord_qa\mid1\implies q\mid (a-1)$ which is impossible as $(a-1,q)=1$

So, $(p,q-1)=p\implies p\mid(q-1)$

But $q-1$ is even as $q$ is odd $\implies 2\mid(q-1)$

So, lcm$(2,p)\mid(q-1)\implies 2p\mid(q-1) $

Comment: in case I you suppose $(p,a)=1$, and in case II Why you conclude $(a-1,q)=1$ from $(p,a)\not = 1$?

Comment: Why you conclude $(a,q)=1$ from $(a-1,q)=1$?

Comment: @agustin, thanks for your feedback and sorry the mistakes.Please find the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** If $q$ is a prime dividing $n$, then since $a^p-1$ is a multiple of $n$ (why?) we also have $q \mid a^p - 1$.  If $a \not\equiv 1 \pmod q$, then this determines the exact multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $q$.  What do you know about $\text{ord}_q(a)$?

On the other hand, if $a \equiv 1 \pmod q$, this tells you a lot about the original sum $n = a^{p-1} + \cdots + 1$ modulo $q$.  What can you then deduce from $q \mid n$?

Comment: if $a\not \equiv 1 \pmod q$ then$ord_q(a)=p$  next step? in case II if $a \equiv 1 \pmod q $ then $q|p-1$ next step?

Comment: @agustin If $\text{ord}_q(a) = p$, what do you know about $\text{ord}_q$ in general?  For the other half, count again: there are $p$ terms in the sum, not $p-1$.

Comment: in case II :$q|p$ since $q,p$ is prime so $q=p$ . in case I $ord_q(a)=\phi(q)=p$that it is impossible because $q-1=p$ odd=even.in case I what do you we?

Comment: @agustin Not quite, $\text{ord}_q(a)$ is not always equal to $\phi(q)$, but it always divides into $\phi(q)$.